# Django Rest Framework and the Frontend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, frontend

I want to use Django Rest Framework as an API and am looking for a way to "couple" the frontend / HTML/CSS/JS to it.
To put it in perspective, I am used to the way Django "usually" does it, by naming HTML templates and 'rendering' them when going to a particular URL.

Now, with DRF, it appears that this functionality has fallen away and everywhere I look it's just "react.js or vue.js" as the answers to consume the API.

What are my options for the front end? Can I not just do it all within the 'usual' Django framework, simply, as it was done before. And why do no resources talk about this?

Thanks, let me know if you require further info.

Comment: If you're creating an API, then you usually want something to consume that API, which would typically be a Javascript client like Vue. If not for this purpose, then for what purpose *are* you using DRF? You can still mix and match all approaches of course: use server-side rendered Django templates, use a Vue app which communicates with the API, serve those Vue files as static files from Django, or serve the Vue files from an entirely different server.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DRF is just additional layer for Django which help to implement API. You can use  Django for render html on server side and serve it to browser. You don't need use DRF for it. But if you assume that you frontend app will be interactive, dynamic and complicated then it is not best way to solve it.

More popular approach suggest to separate it on frontend application (react or vue) and backend with REST API for interact with. It allow move all things related with UI on frontend app and only keep state on server.

By the way Django was developed for generate html on server and for site like this https://www.washingtontimes.com/news/ but world changing. Resources talk just about popular things